# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am trying implmenting datatable but it is giving error:

**Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function**

The Code I am trying is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/styles/components/data-tables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/styles/components/data-tables/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sample_1').dataTable({
        "sDom": "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sPrevious": "Prev",
                "sNext": "Next"
            }
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
            'bSortable': false,
            'aTargets': [0]
        }]
    });
    jQuery('#sample_1 .group-checkable').change(function () {
        var set = jQuery(this).attr("data-set");
        var checked = jQuery(this).is(":checked");
        jQuery(set).each(function () {
            if (checked) {
                $(this).attr("checked", true);
            } else {
                $(this).attr("checked", false);
            }
        });
        jQuery.uniform.update(set);
    });
    jQuery('#sample_1_wrapper .dataTables_filter input').addClass("form-control");
    jQuery('#sample_1_wrapper .dataTables_length select').addClass("form-control");
});
</script>
```

Here is my html code:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped border-top" id="sample_1">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Contract</th>
                    <th>Deposit</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Buy # of Contracts</th>
                    <th>Sell # of Contracts</th>
                    <th>P&amp;L </th>
                    <th>Expiry Time</th>
                    <th>Settlement Payout</th>
                    <th>Fee Payment</th>
                    <th>Sell to Close</th>
                    <th>Buy to Close</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
<tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>04-01-2015</td>
    <td>09:33 AM</td>
    <td>EUR/JPY </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>118</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>-118</td>
    <td>3PM</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>04-01-2015</td>
    <td>09:33 AM</td>
    <td>EUR/JPY </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>118</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>-1.8</td>
    <td>3PM</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>-1.8</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>04-01-2015</td>
    <td>09:43 AM</td>
    <td>EUR/JPY </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>3PM</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>4</td>
    <td>04-01-2015</td>
    <td>09:43 AM</td>
    <td>EUR/JPY </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>-0.9</td>
    <td>3PM</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>-0.9</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>5</td>
    <td>04-01-2015</td>
    <td>09:45 AM</td>
    <td>EUR/JPY </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>3PM</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>6</td>
    <td>04-01-2015</td>
    <td>09:45 AM</td>
    <td>EUR/JPY </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>-0.9</td>
    <td>3PM</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>-0.9</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>7</td>
    <td>04-01-2015</td>
    <td>10:28 PM</td>
    <td>AUD/USD </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>111.5</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>-88.5</td>
    <td>11AM</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>8</td>
    <td>04-01-2015</td>
    <td>10:28 PM</td>
    <td>AUD/USD </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>111.5</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>-1.8</td>
    <td>11AM</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>-1.8</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>9</td>
    <td>04-21-2015</td>
    <td>01:00 PM</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Not familiar with the library but the documentation suggests it's `.DataTable` with a capital D.

Comment: Where is the html code?

Comment: @Juhana it is `.DataTable()` on [this site](https://www.datatables.net), but it is `.dataTable()` [here](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables). Who knows what OP uses...

Comment: @Regent `.dataTable()` works.

Comment: I have tried `.dataTable()` but it didnt

Comment: What jquery version you are using?

Comment: added the html as well. @sgtBOSE

Comment: I am using `jquery-1.8.3.min.js` @sgtBOSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally resolved my problem after trying number of solutions.

The problem was that I am using wrong hierarchy of putting files on one another.

So, firstly it is not the problem nor with the plugin integration but with the proper ordering of files one after another.

This is the final output of my code:

```
<!-- javascripts -->
<script src="../assets/styles/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/styles/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/styles/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap -->
<script src="../assets/styles/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- nice scroll -->
<script src="../assets/styles/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/styles/js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../assets/styles/jquery-knob/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/styles/js/jquery.sparkline.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../assets/styles/components/jquery-easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/styles/js/owl.carousel.js" ></script>

<!-- jQuery full calendar -->
<script src="../assets/styles/components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<!--script for this page only-->
<script src="../assets/styles/js/calendar-custom.js"></script>

<!-- custom select -->
<script src="../assets/styles/js/jquery.customSelect.min.js" ></script>

<!--custome script for all page-->
<script src="../assets/styles/js/scripts.js"></script>

<!-- custom script for this page-->
<script src="../assets/styles/js/sparkline-chart.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/styles/js/easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/styles/components/data-tables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/styles/components/data-tables/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#sample_1').dataTable({
            "sDom": "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sPrevious": "Prev",
                    "sNext": "Next"
                }
            },
            "aoColumnDefs": [{
                'bSortable': false,
                'aTargets': [0]
            }]
        });
        jQuery('#sample_1 .group-checkable').change(function () {
            var set = jQuery(this).attr("data-set");
            var checked = jQuery(this).is(":checked");
            jQuery(set).each(function () {
                if (checked) {
                    $(this).attr("checked", true);
                } else {
                    $(this).attr("checked", false);
                }
            });
            jQuery.uniform.update(set);
        });
        jQuery('#sample_1_wrapper .dataTables_filter input').addClass("form-control");
        jQuery('#sample_1_wrapper .dataTables_length select').addClass("form-control");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -4):

try to change

```
$('#sample_1').dataTable
```

by

```
jQuery('#sample_1').dataTable
```

Comment: If `$` were reassigned it would throw an error earlier at `$(document).ready()`.